# Need help finding the leak in this code please

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);<-----This line gets highlighted as the leak
    [pool release];
    return retVal; 
}
```

It leaks right when I start the app.

Comment: Are you sure that it is top of your stack? It is standard main function contents and it cannot be the source of the problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leak is not there but rather in something the NSApplication calls before the app delegate. Most likely its in an added library or framework. IIRC, a circular reference in a nib can also cause this. Look in your MainWindow nib.

Comment: it only says View "Loaded from RootViewController"