# Memory Leak in Application Main()

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, delegates, memory-leaks

The following code is producing a memory leak on the in retVal line:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];
return retVal;
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200929/need-help-finding-the-leak-in-this-code-please

Answer (score 1):

This probably just means that something created **with** `UIApplicationMain()` is leaking, the code you provided is just fine.
You should have a more detailed look with Instruments.